# Sync Unity config between computers

Tags: 11.10, unity, configuration

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 both at work and at home.

I've made a nice config (from compizconfig-manager like shortcuts, no animations, speedy desktop wall navigation, etc) at work and I want to use it also at home.

So I need to find a way to sync the Unity configurations from work and home both using 11.10... I'm using Ubuntu One and it would be nice if I could sync the computers with it..

Is there a way to do this without copying config files every time I modify the shortcuts on one computer? If no.. then what files do I need to copy to preserve the Unity key-binding/animations, etc.?

Thank you very much :D unity rocks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume UbuntuOne would work (I don't use it much because it doesn't work through firewalls/proxies at work).  But [denNorske is right](https://askubuntu.com/a/98651/43550), [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com) could be used too.

It syncs files in the ~/Dropbox folder it creates, so to have it sync files that need to remain outside that location like configuration file, I believe you can create symlinks to them in ~/Dropbox and the Linux client will then sync the files correctly.  Create such symlinks on both computers to achieve the syncing you want.   The key is to determine which files/folders you need (which maybe someone else can supply).

(Unless they're gconf settings or in some database that contains more than just the compiz or unity settings - you may not want to sync those between computers and change more than just compiz/unity settings.)